# Ubuntu and windows dual-booted no battery warning on windows

Tags: dual-boot, power-management, battery

Sorry if this may be of topic. I got windows 8.1 and Ubuntu dual-booted on my ASUS x550ca. Whenever I'm booted in to Windows while I am on battery power there is no low battery warning warning. It was just fine before installing Ubuntu. It just shuts down at about 10%. I set it to sleep at 5% but it just shuts down. How do I solve this?

Here is a picture of my battery settings on ubuntu [image: My battery settings on ubuntu]

[image: First half of windows settings]

[image: Second half of windows settings]

Answer (score 1):

your battery settings on ubuntu is absolutely correct. ubuntu power settings are not the reason for your problem.
first you should check your power plans on windows 8.1 if the problem remains same then share the picture of your windows power settings.

Comment: I have added some photos. You should see them after the ubuntu settings.

Comment: your windows power settings are also fine there is no need to change anything. one thing you may do restore your default power plan settings if the prblm remains same then contact to nearby service center.

Answer (score 0):

If you are booted into Windows, you need to look at the settings for Windows.

See: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/power-plans-faq#1TC=windows-8